# Extracting Xml Elements from Outerxml type

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Probably another easy one but I cant find the answer and cant work it out.

I have a outerxml packet for example

```
<field1 id="abc" passed="False">
  <field2 id="BCD" reason="yada"/>
</field1>
```

in asp.net (c#) how can I retrieve the value of "reason"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*LINQ to XML*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
string reason = (string)xml.Element("field1").Element("field2").Attribute("reason");
```